# Perl script that extracts data from HTML table

Tags: html, perl, html-table, html-parsing

I need a Perl script to parse a simple HTML table with 2 columns.

The table includes: column 1 Name of the user and column 2 the time that he/she has been online.

I need to get the data as: Name Time_online

I have tried [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) and [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aParser) but without result.

I want somehow to get and manipulate this data. THANK YOU!

```
<h1>Users currently online</h1>
<table class="list-table" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" summary="Data for online_users">
<thead>
<tr class="list-header">
<th class="list-table" id="online_users_name">
User name
</th>
<th class="list-table" align="right" id="online_users_online_time_pretty">
Online time        
</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>  

    <tbody>
              <tr class="odd"> 
              <td class="list-table" headers="online_users_name">
                <a href="Link">Jack Boauldwin</a>
              </td>

              <td class="list-table" align="right" headers="online_users_online_time_pretty">
                11 minutes
              </td>
            </tr>
        <tr class="even">  

              <td class="list-table" headers="online_users_name">
                <a href="Link">Sarah James</a>
              </td>

              <td class="list-table" align="right" headers="online_users_online_time_pretty">
                1 minutes
              </td>            
          </tr>

              <tr class="odd">


              <td class="list-table" headers="online_users_name">
                <a href="Link">Greg Brown</a>
              </td>

              <td class="list-table" align="right" headers="online_users_online_time_pretty">
                0 minutes
              </td>

          </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? Please show you nonworking code and specify what is the current output and what is your desired output.

Comment: Have you considered hiring and paying a programmer?

Comment: @jeremycrews - Don't be so rude as to ignore comments and suggestions from people who are trying to help you help yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [HTML::TableExtract](http://p3rl.org/HTML::TableExtract).

Comment: Indeed. Here's [my response (on my blog) to his previous question](http://blog.nu42.com/2012/04/htmltableextract-is-beautiful.html).

Comment: I got a problem when I tried to install the module. 
It says : 
Fetching with LWP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
And then it gets stuck. Nothing happens for a long time.

Comment: @jeremycrews - It could be a network issue.  Try to manually download and install the module.